# Jquery While Loop Doesn't Work For Some Values

Tags: jquery

There is a weird situation with the `while` loop in my jQuery code. I have a textbox and I want to split the input by `...` and create an array. Then I want to put the array back into the textbox.

For example I put `1...3` and what I want is `1,2,3` in the textbox. The weird part is that the script doesn't work for some values. If I put `1...10` it works however if I try `5...10` nothing happens.

Here is my code, what am I missing? Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").change(function() {
    var val = $("#test").val();
    var val2 = val.split("...");
    var arr = [];
    var valindex1 = val2[0];
    var valindex2 = val2[1];

    while (valindex1 <= valindex2) {
      arr.push(valindex1);
      valindex1++;

    }
    
    if (arr.length != 0) {
      $("#test").val(arr);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was simply that the values from the initial split array were strings, and the string "5" is *not* less than the string "10" - so your `while` loop immediately exists without ever creating the array of numbers.

You can fix it by ensuring `valindex1` and `valindex2` are numbers - the easiest way to do that is preceed the array reads with a `+`. See below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").change(function() {
    var val = $("#test").val();
    var val2 = val.split("...");
    var arr = [];
    var valindex1 = +val2[0];
    var valindex2 = +val2[1];

    while (valindex1 <= valindex2) {
      arr.push(valindex1);
      valindex1++;
    }
    
    if (arr.length != 0) {
      $("#test").val(arr);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Why did it work with "1...10" Im sure you're wondering. It was somewhat luck, as javascript will quite happily evaluate `"1" <= "10"` which happens to be true. When you then within the loop do `valindex1++;` it immediately coerced the string "1" to the number `1` and incremented it. `10...20` would have similarly worked fine as would many other inputs. The fix above will work for *any* input.

Answer (score 2):

after split somehow code is considering values as string instead of number, you can make use of `parseInt` to parse values to integer

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").change(function() {
    var val = $("#test").val();
    var val2 = val.split("...");

    var arr = [];
    var valindex1 = parseInt(val2[0]);
    var valindex2 = parseInt(val2[1]);

    while (valindex1 <= valindex2) {
      arr.push(valindex1);
      valindex1++;
    }
    
    if (arr.length != 0) {
      $("#test").val(arr);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse you string into int :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").change(function() {
    var val = $("#test").val();
    var val2 = val.split("...");
    var arr = [];
    var valindex1 = parseInt(val2[0], 10);
    var valindex2 = parseInt(val2[1], 10);

    while (valindex1 <= valindex2) {
      arr.push(valindex1);
      valindex1++;

    }
    
    if (arr.length != 0) {
      $("#test").val(arr);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```